# How to perform GROUP BY on single table and join that table with another table?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pyspark

I have two tables:

Table1:

| Row1 | Row2 | Common |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x1 | y1 | c1 |
| x2 | y2 | c2 |
| x3 | y3 | c3 |

Table2:

| Common | Value | Other |
| --- | --- | --- |
| c1 | 5 | p1 |
| c1 | 6 | p2 |
| c1 | 10 | p3 |
| c2 | 22 | p4 |
| c2 | 14 | p5 |
| c3 | 6 | p6 |
| c3 | 21 | p7 |
| c3 | 11 | p8 |

Need to join these two tables based on these:

First need to make a temporary table from Table2 using max(Value) group by Common column i.e.:

| Common | Value | Other |
| --- | --- | --- |
| c1 | 10 | p3 |
| c2 | 22 | p4 |
| c3 | 21 | p7 |

Then I need to join this temporary table with Table1 i.e.:

| Row1 | Row2 | Common | Value | Other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x1 | y1 | c1 | 10 | p3 |
| x2 | y2 | c2 | 22 | p4 |
| x3 | y3 | c3 | 21 | p7 |

Now, I need to implement this on PySpark.

I used this snippet:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

Table1.alias("T1").join(
                        Table2.alias("T2"),

                        (col("T1.Common") == col("T2.Common") & col("T2.Value") == T2.groupBy('Common').agg(f.max('Value'))),

                        "left",
                       )
```

But it is failing.

What change should I do?

Basically, I need to make code of this sql query to make that temporary table:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table2
WHERE Value IN(
SELECT max(Value)
FROM Table2
GROUP BY Common);
```

Comment: Will it be better to create a temporary df first, for the Table2, and then join that df with Table1?

Comment: Do you need to keep the value of the `Other` column for the row with the max `Value`? Also it seems like you should be using `F.col` instead of `col` unless it's been imported elsewhere.

Comment: Yup, I need to keep the value of Other column.

Comment: Can there be ties in the `Value` column? What should be done if multiple rows have the same max value?

Comment: In Table2, there will be no tie for the 'Value' columns for exactly one 'Common' data (i.e. C1 or C2). So, there is no tie between two data from 'Other' column also.

Comment: I mean, for the record C1, all Values are distinct.
There may be same value for C1 and C2.

Answer (score 0):

You should be creating the temporary table first and passing it into the join. Also, if you are just joining on column values, passing in a list of column names will automatically combine the 2 tables' columns into one so you don't need to alias them.

```py
max_val = Table2.groupby("Common").agg(f.max("Value").alias("Value")).join(Table2, on=["Common", "Value"])
result_df = Table1.join(max_val, on=["Common"])
result_df.orderBy("Common").show()

+------+----+----+-----+-----+
|Common|Row1|Row2|Value|Other|
+------+----+----+-----+-----+
|    c1|  x1|  y1|   10|   p3|
|    c2|  x2|  y2|   22|   p4|
|    c3|  x3|  y3|   21|   p7|
+------+----+----+-----+-----+
```